# options for running an rb file every hour from a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have an .rb file that contains all my **scraper** /bot related code, and then I want to know where to put it in my rails app so that some rails service activates it and creates the db record with the output.

I have a **scraper** that I made that simply goes on craigslist and pulls data that match my parameters. On my machine, I just had a cron tab job that would execute the .rb file according to the time I specified.

What I want to be able to do is trigger my bot to go out into the world and then create a record in my rails app, so that when a user comes to visit my page.

They can browse through the records that my bot made. So I guess I want my bot to make RESTful resources for me. How do I do that?

I have considered just making my app and then maintaining the bot on my machine and then just sending an http request to my rails app which will be on a VPS,  but I feel like there may be a more ruby esque way to do it.

I've heard the term service object a bit....

Comment: to try and clarify my issue.... I have a rails app that follows the MVC structure. I have some resources, one of those resources ie lets call it Dogs. I also have an plain ole ruby file with various gems attached so that i can go plunder craigslist.... i want thsi ruby file to create a dog record in my rails app.... and i want to activate the ruby.rb file every so offten.

Comment: Something like this? https://www.vikingcodeschool.com/posts/web-scraping-craigslist-with-rubys-mechanize-gem And you wan to store the results in your db. Then a service object or the model itself could do the job, each time you get a result, you can call it and the data is stored in the db. Did I get it right?

Comment: Use https://github.com/javan/whenever to run specific script periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can just answer your question very theoretically as it is lacking some sample code and details about what and how you want to achieve.

Service objects are pure ruby object which are located e.g. in the /lib folder

[This page](https://medium.com/@scottdomes/service-objects-in-rails-75ca74214b77) contains an example:

```
class RegisterUser
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end
  def execute
    return nil unless @user.save
    send_welcome_email
    notify_slack
    if @user.admin?
      log_new_admin
    else
      log_new_user
    end
    @user
  end
  # private methods
end
```

The service object above would be used to create records for new or existing users.

The requests from outside could be API calls to a restful API within your app which receives post requests from outside to generate or modify data in the database.

There are many tutorials outside how to build an API, e.g. [Tutorial 1](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-one) and [Tutorial 2](https://codeburst.io/how-to-build-a-good-api-using-rubyonrails-ef7eadfa3078).

Answer (score 0):

I think Active jobs would be best for this. you can add all .rb files in rails>app>services and create a active job to perform that task. active jobs is used for running any thing in background. you can use sidekiq/rabbitmq to schedule and its easily to integrate with active jobs.

Comment: Ok thanks this is the type of feed back I was looking for. I will dig into this and report back what I found and if i implement a solution using this. Thanks again